# Restricting Target Platform's API usage when developing Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin and i've run into this problem several times already.

I always keep my Target Platform updated for the latest (stable) Eclipse release so that i test my code against all the recent updates, fixes etc.
However, this may (and have) result in accidental breakage of backward compatibility of my plugin, e.g. when i accidentally use new API that did not exist in the Eclipse version i aim to support.
Or, more sneaky example, in 4.6 Eclipse moved to Java 8 and some interface methods got default implementations. Now when i implement these interfaces my IDE doesn't automatically generate empty implementations for those methods and no error is generated. If i install and run this code against a previous Eclipse version these methods will throw `AbstractMethodError` since no implementation has been provided.

So my question is: is there a tool to further restrict API my Target Platform provides to some earlier Eclipse API version?
Is API Baseline an appropriate tool for this? Because i couldn't get it to work like this. (It allowed even non-baseline method calls not to mention the more complex default-methods example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple target platforms, switching between them doesn't take long. For testing Stack Overflow questions I have one Eclipse install with 10 target platforms.

So have a target platform for the oldest release you want to support as well as your current release target platform and check the code runs against that.

It is particularly important to test with the actual Target Platform if you want to support Eclipse 3 releases as the were large changes going from Eclipse 3 to 4.

Comment: Yeah, that's a somewhat ok option. One irritating thing with it though is that many methods were "genrified" in Eclipse API and while new generic implementations compile into backward compatible bytecode, the actual Java code becomes incompatible when switching to older Target Platform.